# Warning NU1603 Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.0-preview1-26926-04

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have windows 10 1809 with target and min versions both build 17763

Using Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.2.0-preview1-26926-04 and Microsoft.UI.XAML v2.1.181025003-prerelease

When I build I see a warning

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1603  Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.0-preview1-
26926-04 depends on Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler (>= 2.2.0-rel-26924-00) 
but Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler 2.2.0-rel-26924-00 was not found. An 
approximate best match of Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler 2.2.0-rel-26924-01 
was resolved.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.0-preview1-
>   26926-04 depends on Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler (>= 2.2.0-rel-26924-00) 
>   but Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler 2.2.0-rel-26924-00 was not found. An 
>   approximate best match of Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler 2.2.0-rel-26924-01 
>   was resolved.

The waring info tells `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler 2.2.0-rel-26924-00` not found. And the best match is `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler` **2.2.0-rel-26924-01**. You could use Package Manager Console to install this with the following command manually.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler -Version 2.2.0-rel-26924-01
```